# Boost serialization with private constructor works in 1.57 not in 1.58

Tags: serialization, boost

Under certain circumstances deserialization of a class with a private constructor does not work with Boost 1.58. In 1.57 it worked fine. The code below, when compiled with Visual Studio 2013, gives the following error message.

error message:

```
1>  SerializeTest.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\vc\include\xmemory0(588): error C2248: 'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'
1>          c:\projects\serializetest\serializetest.cpp(14) : see declaration of 'A::A'
1>          c:\projects\serializetest\serializetest.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'A'
```

code:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int i) {}

private:
    A() {}
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {}

private:
    std::vector<A> m_a;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_a);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
    {
        B b;
        oa & b;
    }

    {
        std::stringstream myIstream;
        myIstream.write(os.str().c_str(), os.str().length());
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(myIstream);

        B b;
        ia >> b;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a Boost regression or an oversight by me?

Comment: I think I ran into this the other day. I blamed myself (because I didn't have an existing code base for that particular problem). You might wanna repoert this in the issue tracker

Comment: Ran into the same problem, +1 for figuring out it was a problem in 1.58, would have taken me a long time

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, look into the xmemory header! For me the error appeared on std::allocator, so i needed to add something like

```
friend class std::allocator<A>;
```

in addition to the friend class for serialization!